# php string in codeigniter

Tags: php, string

PHP string issue using CodeIgniter.
Code:

```
$uIc = $userICPassport->ic;
//uIC = 830112113321
```

the API requirement is the IC number with dash (-).
so i changed the format of uIc into dash format.

```
$uIc = substr($uIc, 0, 6).'-'.substr($uIc, 6);
$uIc = substr($uIc, 0, 9).'-'.substr($uIc, 9);
///Uic =830112-11-3321
```

But after include into parameter array..
'NRIC' => $uIc
The API identify the param is not as string.
Is there anyone can help me on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Include parameter in what ? the problem is here.

Comment: param is not as string ?? what param should be?

Comment: Try 
Your $uIc variables is String itself. Anyway just try below :
$uIc = substr($uIc, 0, 6).'-'.substr($uIc, 6);
$uIc = substr($uIc, 0, 9).'-'.substr($uIc, 9);  
$c=(String)$uIc;     

Then pass $c as arguement.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the output in single quote as below:-

```
$uIC = '830112113321';
$uIc = substr($uIC, 0, 6).'-'.substr($uIC, 6);
$uIc = substr($uIc, 0, 9).'-'.substr($uIc, 9);
echo $uIc; // 830112-11-3321
echo gettype($uIc);  // string
$uIc = "'$uIc'";  // '830112-11-3321'
echo gettype($uIc);  // string
```

Hope it will help you :)